Having issues with Anchor generated IDL file in react project
I am trying to connect React frontend with a Program running in Solana.  It work find with my previous attempt a year ago and i was able to write React frontend and connect with a Program running in Solana testnet. The program was written and deployed with Anchor
But then a month ago i tried to test again but it failed to load IDL file. I build the program with anchor and have it deployed to testnet.  Next i got the IDL file from target/idl folder and copied it in my react project. The problem is occurring when Anchor Program object is being constructed. Here is the code and the error in Visual Studio
  const provider = getProgramProvider();

  const programID = new PublicKey(idl.address);

  const program = new Program(idl, programID, provider);

earlier IDL was imported with     import idl from './idl.json';
Now the error is on the last line above under idl parameter to Program object and here is the error
Argument of type '{ version: string; name: string; address: string; metadata: { name: string; version: string; spec: string; description: string; }; instructions: ({ name: string; discriminator: number[]; accounts: { name: string; writable: boolean; }[]; args: never[]; } | { ...; })[]; accounts: { ...; }[]; types: { ...; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Idl'.
Types of property 'types' are incompatible.
Type '{ name: string; type: { kind: string; fields: { name: string; type: string; }[]; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IdlTypeDef[]'.
Type '{ name: string; type: { kind: string; fields: { name: string; type: string; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IdlTypeDef'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
Type '{ kind: string; fields: { name: string; type: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IdlTypeDefTy'.
As i said a year ago i tested  similar program with no issues
Before this error the message was  name and version properties are not in idl file     i added these 2 properties and then above error start appearing
It seems like for some reacon anchor generated idl file is not acceptable in react project.    i tried to lower @coral-xyz/anchor in react thinking previous versions will treat it well but again i got the same error
The question is why anchor build generated idl file is not acceptable in react.     is it some other issue ?
Shahzad
